# Drop down data not posting "The forum you are trying to create a topic on, does not exist!"

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I created a simple topic post page for a forum. It had a drop down to choose what category the topic belonged to. I have added a second drop down menu for subcategories. The page loads with no errors, but when I try to make a topic "Sports" (category) => "Football"(subcategory), it gives me the error "The forum you are trying to create a topic on, does not exist!"

Here is my code.

```
<?php

$id = mss($_GET['id']);

if ($id) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
    echo "The forum you are trying to create a topic on, does not exist!\n";
} else {
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    if ($row1['admin'] == 1 && $admin_user_level == 0) {
        echo "You are not an administrator, therefore you cannot post on this forum!\n";
    } else {
        if (!$_POST['submit']) {
            echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n";
            echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"./index.php?act=create&id=".$id."\">\n";

            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM forum_cats";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<select name=\"cat\">\n";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo "</select></td></tr>\n";

            $sql = "SELECT cid, name FROM forum_sub_cats";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<select name=\"sub_cat\">\n";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['cid'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo "</select></td></tr>\n";

            echo "<tr><td><textarea name=\"message\" style=\"width:300px;height:100px;\"></textarea></td></tr>\n";
            echo "<tr><td align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Create Topic\"></td></tr>\n";
            echo "</form></table>\n";
        } else {
            $cat = mss($_POST['cat']);
            $msg = mss($_POST['message']);

            if ($cat && $msg) {
                $sql = "SELECT admin FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='" . $cat . "'";
                $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
                    echo "This forum sub category does not exist!\n";
                } else {
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                    if ($row['admin'] == 1 && $admin_user_level != 1) {
                        echo "You are not an admin therefore you cannot post a new topic on this forum!\n";
                    } else {
                            if (strlen($msg) < 3 || strlen($msg) > 10000) {
                                echo "The message must be between 3 and 10,000 characters!\n";
                            } else {
                                $date = date("m-d-y") . " at " . date("h:i:s");
                                $time = time();
                                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `forum_topics` (`cid`,`uid`,`date`,`time`,`message`) VALUES('" .
                                    $cat . "','" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "','" . $date . "','" . $time .
                                    "','" . $msg . "')";
                                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                                $tid = mysql_insert_id();
                                topic_go($tid);
                            }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Please supply all the fields!\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
} else {
     if (!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n";
            echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"./index.php?act=create&id=".$id."\">\n";

            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM forum_cats";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<select name=\"cat\">\n";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo "</select></td></tr>\n";

            $sql = "SELECT id, name FROM forum_sub_cats";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            echo "<select name=\"sub_cat\">\n";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['cid'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo "</select></td></tr>\n";


    echo "<tr><td><textarea name=\"message\" style=\"width:300px;height:100px;\"></textarea></td></tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Create Topic\"></td></tr>\n";
    echo "</form></table>\n";
} else {
    $cat = mss($_POST['cat']);
    $msg = mss($_POST['message']);

    if ($cat && $msg) {
        $sql = "SELECT admin FROM `forum_sub_cats` WHERE `id`='" . $cat . "'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
            echo "This forum sub category does not exist!\n";
        } else {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            if ($row['admin'] == 1 && $admin_user_level != 1) {
                echo "You are not an admin therefore you cannot post a new topic on this forum!\n";
            } else {

                    if (strlen($msg) < 3 || strlen($msg) > 10000) {
                        echo "The message must be between 3 and 10,000 characters!\n";
                    } else {
                        $date = date("m-d-y") . " at " . date("h:i:s");
                        $time = time();
                        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `forum_topics` (`cid`,`uid`,`date`,`time`,`message`) VALUES('" .
                            $cat . "','" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "','" . $date . "','" . $time .
                            "','" . $msg . "')";
                        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
                        $tid = mysql_insert_id();
                        header("Location: index.php?act=topic&id=" . $tid . "");
                    }

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please supply all the fields!\n";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a form field named `id`, `$id = mss($_GET['id']);`, but the only `select` elements you create are `cat` or `sub_cat`. Either name one of those `id` or change what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I changed sub_cat to id, still the same error, I don't think I linked them properly maybe, as the sub categories were originally in a drop down WITH the categories but I split them up.

Comment: @user2542256, one other thing to note is that you're only setting `name`, you actually need to set `id`.

Comment: Sorry not sure if I've been looking at this too long or I am just tired but can you please be more specific.

Comment: @user2542256, there is a line `echo "<select name=\"sub_cat\">\n";` that needs to be modified to say `echo "<select name=\"sub_cat\" id=\"sub_cat\">\n";` because the posted form uses `id`. If there are any others like that you'll need to fix them too.

Comment: Still no luck, here is 2 examples of the changes I made (dont want to post the whole file)
echo "<select name=\"cat\" id=\"cat\">\n";
echo "<select name=\"sub_cat\" id=\"sub_cat\">\n";

Comment: @user2542256, and did you change the line `$_GET['id']` to `$_GET['sub_cat']`?

Comment: Ok turns out I am getting the error message saying "The forum you are trying to create a topic on, does not exist!" but it's actually being entered into my database, I'll have to have another look in the morning at something else I'm doing wrong.